# question regarding the use of interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, oop, interface

Jumping into the question straight away.

Scenario-Steps:

1) I defines an interface

```
IMathBase 
{
   void Add(int a , int b);
   void Sub(int a, int b);
}
```

2) A Concrete class `PlusMinus` implements `IMathBase`.

3) A Concrete class `PlusMinusDiv` implements `IMathBase`. `PlusMinusDiv` adds another function `void Div(int a, int b)`

4) `IMathBase mathBase = new PlusMinusDiv();`

5) `mathBase.Div(10,20)`;

I know the step 5 is invalid. What is the best way to deal with the above situation[ to add a new method to  a concrete class which implements a common interface]?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Joe

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a pointer do you mean for this to occur in an unsafe code block and is there a reason you can't just use normal c# references.

Comment: @rerun. Thanks for pointing that out. Removed the *. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

```
PlusMinusDiv mathBase = new PlusMinusDiv();
mathBase.Div(10,20);
```

or

```
IMathBase mathBase = new PlusMinusDiv();
((PlusMinusDiv)mathBase).Div(10,20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either add the new method to the interface and implement it in all the concrete classes or give your variable a type of PlusMinusDiv rather than IMathBase. The correct answer just depends on the needs of your application.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you could handle this, you could:

1.Simply add the new method to the interface definition, and update any existing implementations.

2.As above, but use an abstract base class which can provide a default implementation. That way any existing implementations that inherit from your abstract base class won't break, and can optionally override the implementation provided by the base class.

3.Use an extension method, e.g.:

```
public static int Div(this IMathBase mathBase, int a, int b) {
    return (a / b);
}

int result = mathBase.Div(20, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces in C# support inheritance.  So, you can add a new interface, such as IDivMath, that inherits from IMathBase, such as in this example:

```
public interface IMathBase
{
    void Sub(int x, int y);
    void Add(int x, int y);
}

public interface IDivMath : IMathBase
{
    void Div(int x, int y);
}
```

So, just have your class implement the IDivMath interface, which includes the methods in IMathBase:

```
public class PlusMinusDiv() : IDivMath
{
    public void Div(int x, int y)
    {}
    public void Add(int x, int y)
    {}
    public void Sub(int x, int y)
    {}
}
```

and you can reference your class using either interface, depending on how you plan to use the class:

```
 IMathBase* mathBase = new PlusMinusDiv();
 IDivMath* divMath = new PlusMinusDiv();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling **Div** method which was not defined in the interface, then you must know about existance of that method and the context where you plan to use it.

I would say that there is no concrete answer to your question because you didn’t provide enough details. It might happen that implementing another interface with defined **Div** method will be perfect for you. Or maybe the context is very simple and you can just instantiate your class with the pointer of exact type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in .Net 4 you can also do:

```
dynamic mathBase = new PlusMinusDiv();
mathBase.Div(10,20);
```

which is more or less the same as

```
PlusMinusDiv mathBase = new PlusMinusDiv();
mathBase.Div(10,20);
```